# How to control eviction threads settings of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database-performance

I found in the [wiredtiger-eviction-thresholds](https://muralidba.blogspot.com/2018/03/wiredtiger-eviction-thresholds.html) page the default min/max eviction threads settings of MongoDB. This page lists the valid values for each settings. However, I didn't find how actually I change any of the defaults. I searched MongoDB documentation and didn't any parameter that can control it either from command line or in the configuration file.. 
As My application is in Perl, I searched in addition [Official MongoDB Driver for Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB) for such API but didn't find any.

How can I change those defaults?

Comment: Why do you want to change them? They are difficult to change precisely because you don't need to.

Comment: My storage + memory has long latency. Under load of changes I get snowball that ends with timeouts. 
I've very sure that by increasing the number of eviction threads, I'll be able to get smooth operation without decreasing the throughput the system can handle inserts.

Comment: @kevinadi: Could you please explain me or refer me on how to change those parameters?
I looked once again into my environment, and I don't see how to fix without a significant slow down the rate of my inserts. 
I tried looking into the source code as well. I noticed the parameter `--inMemoryEngineConfigString` but mongod returned `unrecognised option` error when I tried to use it. 
I don't have very much experience searching in source-code so I may be missing it.